# RelayCommand RaiseCanExecuteChanged() fails

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, mvvm-light, relaycommand

I am using a couple of Buttons bound to RelayCommands initialized with CanExecute delegates.

```
RelayCommand DeleteCommand;
bool CanDelete()
{
    return BoolProp1 && BoolProp2;
}

...

DeleteCommand = new RelayCommand(Delete, CanDelete);
```

`BoolProp1` and `BoolProp2` are regular properties with setters correctly raising `PropertyChanged`, but as we all know, this is not enough to make SL reevaluate `CanExecute` on commands. That's why i also call `Delete.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` in both setters.

All this works fine (buttons are disabled and enabled properly) up to some point, where is all stops. At that point, calling `Delete.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` no longer fires my breakpoints in `CanDelete()` and buttons forever stay the way they were.

I spend 2 hours trying to isolate the exact cause with no effect. I suspect multiple `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` calls during single "binding iteration" somehow break the mechanism.

Any hints? I'm already considering using an additional `IsExecutable` field refreshed through `INotifyPropertyChanged`...

**UPDATE**

`RelayCommand` is actually `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand` from [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/). ILSpy shows a pretty trivial implementation of ICommand:

```
public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    return this._canExecute == null || this._canExecute.Invoke();
}

public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
{
    EventHandler canExecuteChanged = this.CanExecuteChanged;
    if (canExecuteChanged != null)
    {
         canExecuteChanged.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

with `_canExecute` being a `Func<bool>` set once to the value passed to constructor.

I am still working to minimally reproduce the issue.

**UPDATE**

See my answer.

Comment: Post more code.  What is RelayCommandEx?  What does the command implementation look like?  Create a very simple repro and post full code if possible.

Comment: ``RelayCommandEx`` was my failed attempt to deal with this (tried caching CanExecute() value and not firing CanExecuteChanged if not needed).

Comment: I have a vague memory of running into this, and it had to do with something (I think in my case it was the WPF Button) was not caching the EventHandler and weak references. Will try to figure out what it was when I have time, but may help get you on the right path. You may want to implement add/remove accessors for the CanExecuteChanged event and then set a breakpoint in the remove to see when it's being removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PEBKAC. My framework in certain cases ran the code

```
DeleteCommand = new RelayCommand(Delete, CanDelete);
```

more then once, overwriting commands that were actually bound to view with new instances.

If somebody has this problem - make sure you're calling `RelayCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` on the same instance that the view is bound to.

Answer (score 0):

*For anyone else who faced the same issue and the accepted answer didn't help me (and for my own record, as I spent a few hours today with it).*

If you're using MVVM Light in a VSTO add-in, make sure that the Office application gets a chance to process its own messages to get this to work. For example, in my case I had my Ribbon buttons listening to `CanExecuteChanged` of underlying VM's command objects, which would not fire no matter what I did. After spending a few hours, I realized that I had to let Office application take a breath and process incoming message to allow `CanExecuteChanged` to be caught by the add-in. What I then did was to hand over my `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` function to `DispatcherHelper` to let it fire asynchronously. It was only then that my Ribbon buttons started reacting to `CanExecuteChanged` events. Something like this:

```
DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
{
  doc.Activate();
  ResetVariablesCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
});
```